# Are there any prepaid mobile data cards that cover more than one non-EU balkan states?

Tags: europe, data-plans, roaming, balkans

I am planning a rail trip through the Balkans, but I would like to have a internet connection in case of any problems.

One option would be to buy a new prepaid sim card in every country, but that would mean I will have no data from the point I cross the border until I buy a new one.

The ideal solution would be a prepaid sim card that would allow you to use your data across the whole Balkans/Europe, but as far as I know, no such cards exist.

However, I remember that before the abolition of roaming in EEA, there was a prepaid card in Slovakia that you could also use in Czech republic. Are there any similar cards in the Balkans, for instance, a card that you could use both in Bulgaria and North Macedonia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around on the internet, I found that a kosovar sim card could be the solution I was looking for.

According to the information on [prepaid data sim wiki](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Kosovo), currently all kosovar operators allow you to use roaming data in select balkan countries for a cheaper price than the cost of a new sim card. One operator even has the same prices in Albania as in Kosovo.

I haven't found any similar sim cards in other countries.